# Google Maps Style for Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

I am working on a Flutter app with google maps.
Is there a way to get the map style used in google maps app somewhere?

The standard style has roads with a yellowish color while the roads on google maps app are different shades of grey.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

controller.setMapStyle Use this code. You can create your own style from [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

```html
[
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f6e54c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```